# Styling Radio inputs issue

Tags: html, css, forms, input, radio-button

I want to style radio input INSIDE "label" tags. I already changed the background color, however when im clicking on my radio white dot inside doesn't show up. I wrote a code for that and I really don't know what the problem is.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <style>
      label {
        display: inline-block;
        cursor: pointer;
        position: relative;
        padding-left: 25px;
        margin-right: 15px;
        font-size: 13px;
        display:block;
      }

      input[type=radio] {
        display: none;
      }

      label:before {
        content: "";
        display: inline-block;
        width: 17px;
        height: 17px;
        margin-right: 10px;
        position: absolute;
        left: 0;
        bottom: 1px;
        background-color: #ff7900;
        box-shadow: inset 0px 2px 3px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, .3), 0px 1px 0px 0px rgba(255, 255, 255, .8);
        border-radius: 8px;
      }

      input[type=radio]:checked + label:before {
        content: "\2022";
        color: #f3f3f3;
        font-size: 30px;
        text-align: center;
        line-height: 18px;
        position: absolute;
      }

      .input {
        font-size: 20px;
        font-weight: bold;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form>
      <label class="input"><input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe">xxxxxxxx</label>
      <label class="input" ><input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe">xxxxxxx</label>
      <label class="input"><input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe">xxxxxxx</label>\
      <label class="input"><input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe">xxxxxxx</label>
    </form>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: There is no parent selector in css

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This:

```
input[type=radio]:checked + label:before
```

requires that the `label` immediately follow the input.

However, your HTML is

```
 <label class="input"><input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe">xxxxxxxx</label>
```

The label surrounds the input and so the selector will not work.

You would need

```
<input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe"/><label class="input">xxxxxxxx</label>
```

Alternatively; use a pseudo-element on a `span` inside the label rather than the label itself

```
 <label class="input">
   <input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe">
   <span>xxxxxxxx</span>
 </label>
```

with

```
input[type=radio]:checked + span:before
```

Comment: Okay, but how an I fix it with input INSIDE label? :)

Comment: @MikołajPopieluch you need **any** node after the input. You can put, let's say `span` after the `input` **inside** the `label`

Comment: Add for to select radio clicking label: <input type="radio" name="number" class="hehe" for="xyz"/><label id="xyz" class="input">xxxxxxxx</label>

Comment: @MikołajPopieluch is you read the comments in your question there are not parent selector in CSS, so you can't stylish an input INSIDE label knowing the state of that checkbox. You only can make this with sibling selectors as this answer provides.

Answer (score -1):

You can try this code.
What Paulie said is correct.

```css
label {
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-left: 30px;
  cursor: pointer;
}
input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}
input[type=radio] + label:before {
  content: '';
  width: 24px;
  height: 24px;
  background: tomato;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: middle;
  margin-right: 5px;
  z-index: 5;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
}
input[type=radio]:checked + label:after {
  content: '';
  width: 16px;
  height: 16px;
  background: white;
  border-radius: 50%;
  display: inline-block;
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  top: 4px;
  left: 4px;
}
div {
  margin-bottom: 15px;
  position: relative;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="one">
  <label for="one">XXXXXXXXXXXX</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="two">
  <label for="two">xxxx</label>
</div>
<div>
  <input type="radio" name="test" id="three" checked>
  <label for="three">xxxxxxxxxxxxx</label>
</div>
```

Comment: If you find any answer in-appropriate, so while DownVoting it, have the courtesy to explain it in comments. Unless it's the wrong answer